# Disable autoincrementing id inside of ActiveRecord::Base.transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, service-object

I have a `FormObject` for registration which creates a user and a **lot** of models for him inside `create` method.

```
def create
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    @user = User.create(@params[:user])
    process_bonuses_for_user
    process_actions_for_user
    # et.c., giant amount of methods
  end

  @user.persisted? # to return the true of false to controller
end
```

I met the strange behaviour of my `FormObject`. Even it ran successfull (create a lot of models) or unsuccessful (not saving them), the `id` of `User` model is autoincrementing. So, every trying to save something using my `FormObject` increment the value of next `id` for User. This is normal situation when `User` created successfully, but not normal when user makes a mistake on registration form.

How can I disable this unpredictable behaviour?

P.S. I know that everything is work when I write `@user = User.new(@params[:user])` at the start of `create` method and `@user.save` at the end, but there are a lot of associations, and I don't want to write a lot of `autosave` or `inverse_of` in my models.

P.P.S. I'm `postgresql-9.4` user

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction is not working because you're using `create`. You need to use the bang version (`create!`) to raise an exception on failure which triggers the rollback. Do note that you'll need to `rescue` the `InvalidRecord` exception yourself.

Comment: Hmm... Seems like overkill

Comment: It's the only way to make sure your `transaction` works. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it could be something like this:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
         process_bonuses_for_user
         process_actions_for_user
         # et.c., giant amount of methods
         ...
         format.html { redirect_to ... }
      end
    end
```

Comment: Wrong. What will be if user is valid, but `process_actions_for_user` method failed?

Comment: So, if `process_actions_for_user` related to `User Model`,  it should be placed into verification area. If it related to other models, user should be ceated before it. Yes? Other case -- You could use before_action: and after_action: filters...